# How Face Recognision  Use in Java 

Tags: java

Please Help me I need to recognition Human Face up to now i'm Detect Faces using JavaCV Wrapper libraries but JavaCV not support for Recognision the Faces Please Help me also :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you: [Face Detection in Java](http://www.richardnichols.net/2011/01/java-facial-recognition-haar-cascade-with-jjil-guide/)